# H2 Database Delete Records Older than particular Days

Tags: sql, h2, sql-delete, datetime-parsing

I have to delete all the records from H2 Database by matching `completed_date` column with current time stamp where difference in days are greater than 1 (or an number of days).

There is one problem with the schema of database that `completed_date` is stored as String in the given format `11-Jan-2018 15:35:30 PM` i.e `'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa'` format.

There are some more parameters where status should be matched.

I am getting this Exception

> Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "28-12-2017 03:12:47"; SQL statement:

The query I have written is as below.

```
delete from TABLE_NAME
where 
status = 'status1'
OR status = 'status2'
OR status = 'status3' 
AND
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,TO_CHAR(PARSEDATETIME(completed_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss    
aaa'),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) >= 1;
```

In above query I have found that TIMESTAMPDIFF does not work with date format dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa so first I have tried to parse it in 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' format and if use this below query it gives me proper result

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(PARSEDATETIME('2017-OCT-2017 15:49:47 PM','dd-MMM-yyyy 
HH:mm:ss aaa') 
,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Just giving some more information that i am coding Workfusion which is RPA tool which internally uses h2-database so if anyone from workfusion here they can also help me.

Comment: What a stupid tool that stores timestamps in a VARCHAR column. I always wonder why people responsible for such stupid design decisions are never forced to work with what they have done.

Comment: A tool can store it in Date Time Format but somehow mistake was done. Just want the RESOLUTION now , Please.

Comment: No in the Database i can see it store in this format 11-Jan-2018 15:35:30 PM

Comment: Please [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table in question.

Comment: Got the Solution Thanx for helping...

Comment: Your assumption that a `timestamp` value has "a format" makes me think that the table doesn't really store them as a `varchar`, so to make sure that the approach using `parsedatetime()` is really the correct one, it is necessary to actually see the DDL for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timestampdiff()` takes two timestamps as the input, however you are passing a string and a timestamp. So the string gets converted back to a timestamp using some default format.

You should be using:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,PARSEDATETIME(completed_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

(assuming that `parsedatetime()` can successfully parse the string)

Comment: It Worked ! Thank you So Much ....just need to understand one thing here that does TIMESTAMPDIFF can work with two different formats of Date?

Comment: @NitinRathod A `timestamp` (or `date`)  value does **not** have "a format" - that's the whole point of using the correct data type. You can _output_ that value in any format you like, but internally it's a binary value. Any format you _see_ is applied when printing/displaying that value (e.g. by your SQL client) - your assumption that a `timestamp` value has "a format" makes me think that the table doesn't really store them as a `varchar`....

Comment: So if The 'completed_date' been stored as Date & Time format in the databse then i would  not have to used PARSEDATETIME , correct? directly putting completed_date would have worked ?

Comment: @NitinRathod: correct. That's why I asked for the table definition

Comment: Oh...Ok ! Thanx for your Inputs.

Comment: Select * from @this 
           WHERE 
           status = 'TRANSFERRED'     OR
           status = 'scase_is_pulled' OR 
           status = 'SUCCESS'         AND
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,PARSEDATETIME(completed_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy'),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ) > 40 LIMIT 1;                                                 This query is giving me this error - Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 226